# G-WAN: adding .jar application to CLASSPATH: "try catch not catching exception"

Tags: java, exception, g-wan

I'm trying to use to G-WAN webserver. So I added a ".jar" application to CLASSPATH in order to call it from java servlet.
The code is running, but it is unable to catch the exception, and the application crashes.
Below you can find the output:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No frame selected.



Signal        : 11:Address not mapped to object
Signal src    : 1:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 2
Code   Pointer: 7f22eda66ac7 module:libjvm.so function:Arena::set_size_in_bytes(unsigned long) line:0
Access Address: 000000000020
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if G-WAN Java examples were running fine in the first place (even with exception handling)?

If so, your loaded .jar is the place to start with - or maybe the way the JVM loaded it from G-WAN's servlet.

That's clearly a JVM class loader issue but investigating it would require using your exact same .jar and settings, and digging into JVM internals.

Comment: Dear, I added an exception in the G-WAN Java example "hello.java". But I got the same error. The update hello.java:
import api.Gwan;
import org.mainpackage.*;

public class hello // the class name MUST match the script *.java filename
{
   public static int jmain(long env, String[] args) 
   {
 try{
  int testig = 100/0;
 }catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("handling exception");
  Gwan.xbufCat(Gwan.getReply(env), "Hello, Java! Handling Exception");
 }
      return 200;
   }
}

Comment: Output:  The output: 
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No frame selected.
Signal        : 11:Address not mapped to object
Signal src    : 1:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 1
Code   Pointer: 7fb2c640eac7 module:libjvm.so function:Arena::set_size_in_bytes(unsigned long) line:0
Access Address: 000000000020
Registers : EAX=000000c9e3a8 CS=00000033 EIP=7fb2c640eac7 EFLGS=000000010206
EBX=7fb2abff9f90 SS=ffffffff ESP=7fb2abffa250 EBP=7fb2abffa290
ECX=7fb250000030 DS=ffffffff ESI=0000000003d8 FS=00000033
EDX=7fb250001710 ES=ffffffff